# How do I put a php statement inside a php statement?

Tags: php

```
<?php cp_latest_tweet('<?=$next_fixture?>'); ?>
```

The `next_fixture` part is where I'm having trouble. How do I go about this?

Comment: string in single quotes doesn't evaluate variables. Use double quotes.

Comment: I thought he was trying to pass the string literal to the function, not echo the variable to the function =P

Comment: Yo dawg, I heard you like php... :)

Comment: @rmflow: Came here to post this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why the hell would you do that?

Simply pass the var directly:

```
<?php cp_latest_tweet($next_fixture); ?>
```

---

If you want to have a string before/after it, e.g.:

```
<?php '<div>' . cp_latest_tweet($next_fixture) . '</div>'; ?>
```

or

```
<div><?php cp_latest_tweet($next_fixture); ?></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you mean:

> How do I call a function using a variable instead of a string literal?

```
<?php cp_latest_tweet($next_fixture); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you got this fixed yet, the previous two answers are correct but do you know where the variable $next_fixture exists? if it's in the same script where you CALL the function then you should have no problem, but if it's in another script called something like next_fixture.php you will have to include this script in the one your calling the function from. If this is the case you can use require_once:

require_once('next_fixture.php');

and then:

cp_latest_tweet($next_fixture);